# How to schedule a google cloud function to trigger the nearest second?

Tags: node.js, typescript, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have tried scheduling a cloud function with the Pub/Sub trigger method working with crontabs, unfortunately, it seems to give granularity to the closes minute. For my purpose, I am building an app that needs to work with trades at very accurate timeframes. Is there a way to schedule a function to the closest second of a timestamp using node.js?

Comment: Google Cloud Pub/Sub and Cloud Functions are not real-time systems. When you factor in cold start time, you cannot achieve this level of time scheduling.

Answer (score 0):

The cloud function trigger configuration uses Unix-Cron, and the lowest granularity you can get using it is a minute based granularity, as referenced on this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/configuring/cron-job-schedules?&_ga=2.130521743.-1296014413.1579530907&_gac=1.49598354.1581084883.EAIaIQobChMIofqpktC_5wIVh8x3Ch0sdAn1EAAYASAAEgKyF_D_BwE#defining_the_job_schedule).

That being said, what you could do as a workaround, is to adapt your function to repeat itself a few times during execution within this minute timebox you have set, here is an useful [community post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11102/cron-running-job-every-15-seconds) related to that.